# How to jQuery toggle conditionally and add classname?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have a button, that when clicked does add a classname "in" or if "in" exists already remove it.

It does add the "in" class but once set it doesn't remove it when clicked again.

How can I add "in" to class "collapse" and remove it when clicked again?

```js
  $(document.getElementById("toggle-expand-sections")).click(function() {
    if ($('#toggle-expand-sections').hasClass("enabled")) {
      $('#description-form .collapse').addClass("in");
    } else {
      $('#description-form .collapse').removeClass("in");
      $('#toggle-expand-sections').addClass("enabled");
    }
    $('#toggle-expand-sections .toggle').toggle();
  });
```

```css
#toggle-expand-sections {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 2rem;
}

.collapse {
 display: none;
} 

.in {
 display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/js/font-awesome.min.js" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle-expand-sections" class="btn btn-info">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-off toggle" title="expand all sections"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on toggle" style="display: none" title="collapse all sections"></i>
</button>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up `.toggleClass()` ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't work because `$('#toggle-expand-sections').addClass("enabled")` means that `hasClass('enabled')` will always be `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly didn't know the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method...
***Description:*** *Display or hide the matched elements.*

See how it reduces your code (and chances of error, be it logical or syntaxic).

```js
// Toggle "Expand/Collapse All Sections" Button
$('#toggle-expand-sections').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.toggle').toggle();
  $(".collapse").toggle();
});



/*
  if ($('#toggle-expand-sections').hasClass("enabled")) {
    $('#toggle-expand-sections').removeClass("enabled");
    $('.collapse').removeClass("in");
  } else {
    $('.collapse').addClass("in");
    $('#toggle-expand-sections').addClass("enabled");
  }
});
*/
```

```css
#toggle-expand-sections {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.collapse {
  display: none;
}

/*
.in {
  display: block !important;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/js/font-awesome.min.js" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle-expand-sections" class="btn btn-info">
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-off toggle" title="expand all sections"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-toggle-on toggle" style="display: none" title="collapse all sections"></i>
</button>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">foo</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="collapse">
  <div class="subheader-description">baz</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use toggleClass method of jQuery?

```
$(function() {
    $("#yourbutton").on("click", function() {
        $("#yourelement").toggleClass("in");
    ))
});
```